# Add config forms to existing admin page

Tags: 8, forms, routes

Instead of creating a new route and menu:

```
  amustatuscode.config:
  path: '/admin/config/statuscode/config'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\amu_http_status_code_display\Form\AmuHttpStatusCodeDisplayConfigForm'
    _title: 'HTTP status code error messages'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer http status code'


amustatuscode.config:
  title: 'AMU HTTP status code'
  description: 'Customize HTTP status code error messages'
  parent: system.admin_config
  route_name: amustatuscode.config
  weight: 100
```

How can I add this form to the existing basic site settings?

> /admin/config/system/site-information

Answer (score 2):

You could extend the default form by using a Route subscriber.
To do so, create a file named RouteSubscriber.php whithin your module in a src/Routing folder.

the file should look like this:

```
<?php 
namespace Drupal\YOUR_MODULE\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('system.site_information_settings')) 
      $route->setDefault('_form', 'Drupal\YOUR_MODULE\Form\ExtendedSiteInformationForm');
  }

}
```

You should then create a ExtendedSiteInformationForm.php file within your module src/Form folder like that:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\YOUR_MODULE\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\system\Form\SiteInformationForm;


class ExtendedSiteInformationForm extends SiteInformationForm {

   /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
   $form=  parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
   //update your $form...
   return $form;
}
}
```

This way you won't need your routing.yml file anymore.

Comment: mm i am not entering alterRoutes method !?

Comment: Then why don't simply use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id)? add your fields and your submit and it should work!

Comment: @nikko you missed one thing. The RouteSubscriber class must be registered as a service. The module needs a {module_name}.services.yml file registering the class. More details in the link below.
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones

Comment: @JorgeCalderon I believe you'd better post a new answer, saying "In complement to Nikko's answer, you should do this and that...." rather than editing actual answer ? Cheers.